# WCF compatibility with visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, vsta

I create a service layer with WCF in server. when i call service  methods in VS 2012 every think work well but when i am going to use these  services in info path with using visual studio tools  for application (vsta), when i call these service in vsta that has .net2 in vs 2005, my problems are as following:
when all data members with int data type transfer to server,they convert to zero and all data members with bool data type transfer to server, they convert to false.
i don't know the reason but i guess maybe wcf is not compatible with VS 2005
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

WCF was introduced in .NET 3.0 so basically you can't use it with net20. You have 2 options:

1) You can install 4.0 framework separatly from VS2005 and use its command line tools to generate proxy classes for your service and upgrade your project to a new framework too.

2) You can take sources of mono implementation of wcf and try to compile it with .net20 and include it in your project. But the support of WCF in Mono is not complete.